# How to use "audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback" in a few different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a listener in a view controller to detect the volume buttons pressings...

```
void audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID *inID, UInt32 *inDataSize, const void *inData)
{ 
// My Code
}
```

And in a "ViewDidAppear" I have…

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback, CFBridgingRetain(self));
```

How can I use this listener in a few different views?
If I'm adding this code into the two different views, my program crashes during the compiling.
And if you know a solution, can you write it in details, including the code, please. It will help me to understand the IOS programming deeper.

Comment: the app can not crash during compile, but you will get an error during compile. Maybe a missing header?

Comment: No, I think, it is because I'm calling the "audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback" twice.